# A question related to the local compactness of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology. Suppose we have an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the equivalence classes are $\mathbb{Z}$ and single non-integer points. Let $q: \mathbb{R}\to Y$ be the corresponding quotient map, so $Y$ is given by identifying all the integers to a single point, say $\alpha$, and is given the quotient topology.

I am trying like to show that $Y$ is not locally compact by proving that $\alpha$ doesn't have a compact neighborhood, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any help/hint will be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: One way is to use Tietze extension theorem to build an unbounded function from every compact neiberhood K of α(in the sense that it is contains an open neighberhood of α) - try first to build it on $q^{-1}(K)$ such that the function would be constant on $\mathbb Z$ and then take the induced map to the quotient space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I cannot use Tietze extension theorem to prove this claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume by contradiction that Y is locally compact thus there exist an open neighberhood V of $\alpha$ and a compact set $C$ such that $\alpha \in V \subseteq C$.

From continouty of $q$ we have that $W=q^{-1}(V)$ is open, we also have that $\mathbb Z \subseteq W$. now for every $n \in \mathbb Z$ we can choose $\frac{1}{2}>r_n>0$ such that $B(n,r_n) \subseteq W$. notice that for every $i \neq j \in \mathbb Z$ we have that $B(i,r_i) \cap B(j,r_j) = \emptyset$.

now we define for every $n \in \mathbb Z$, $B_n = B(n,\frac{r_n}{2})$. thus we have $B_n \subseteq \overline{B_n} \subseteq B(n,r_n) \subseteq W.$

and now define $C^{'} = \cup_{n \in \mathbb Z} \overline{B_n}$. notice that $C^{'}$ is close and thus from the fact that $q$ is a close map(as you asked in another question) we get that $q(C^{'})$ is a close subset of $C$ which is compact and thus $q(C^{'})$ is compact, but it is not as can be seen by the covering
$U = \{q(B(i,r_i) \cup_{i\neq j \in Z} B_j)\}_{n \in \mathbb Z}$